moveToElement is firefox headless mode not working properly
moveToElement is firefox headless mode not working properly.Where the same working in visible browser.
Tried
action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
but it did't work as expected in firefox headless
Here is my options
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            // Headless mode
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            // Ignore SSL errors
            options.addPreference("network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist", false);  // Disable HSTS preload
            options.addPreference("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", true); // Trust root certificates
            // Maximize window
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            // Disable infobars (similar behavior in Firefox is to block warning popups)
            options.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false); // Disable notifications
            // Disable Automation detection
            options.addPreference("dom.webdriver.enabled", false);
            options.addPreference("useAutomationExtension", false);
            
            options.addPreference("gfx.direct2d.disabled", true);
            options.addPreference("layers.acceleration.disabled", true);
            options.setCapability("moz:webdriverClick", false);
            // Set window size
            options.addArguments("--width=1920");
            options.addArguments("--height=1080");  
            
            
            
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

